# Trouble Installing Certain Modules

Tags: azerothcore

I'm having issues getting some modules to install.  I've been able to get mod-1v1-arena and mod-npc-free-professions working, but I haven't been able to get these other modules to work:

mod-new-character-perks
mod-learn-spells
mod-quick-teleport

Can someone please confirm I have the correct workflow, or advise on what steps I'm missing.

1. Clone module folder from git to .\azerothcore-wotlk\modules
2. Run Git CLI: ./acore.sh docker build
3. Copy mod_learnspells.conf to .\azerothcore-wotlk\env\docker\etc\modules

I see instructions about rebuilding with CMake, is that necessary if I'm using docker build...? I tried CMake too and I got an error immediately with the software setup, so haven't pursued it further.

I'm also a bit confused by the .conf files, which folder does the server read them from?

.\azerothcore-wotlk\env\docker\etc\modules or .\azerothcore-wotlk\modules\mod-learn-spells\conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to install without any modules to check for the core stability and then work up from there one by one.

This way, if there's a module that's currently not working due to recent PR's like the `Autobalance` and possibly `mod-learn-spells` you can report an issue and work without it until It's back up.

AzerothCore Continuous Integration build with modules is currently failing aswell if you check the [Readme notes](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) where it says [image]